# Bootstrap Vue Progress Bar cannot get its value from function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using Bootstrap Vue to display a progress bar. The HTML part is as follows:

```
<b-progress :value="getOverallScore" :max=5 variant="primary" animated></b-progress>
```

`getOverallScore` is a computed function. It returns an average value of three different scores.

```
    computed: {
    getOverallScore: function () {
        var i;
        var sum = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + this.items[i].score;
        }
        return Number.parseFloat(sum / this.items.length).toFixed(2);
    },


}
```

When I tested the output using `<h5>Overall scores: {{ getOverallScore }}</h5>` it works perfectly, but the progress bar cannot get a value from the function. Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the value of the getOverallScore computed before the items arrive from the api?

Comment: For now the values are hard-coded, the computed function get its data from data () section. I will edit that comment out to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're in the right range?

Perhaps your values range from [0,100] and the expected value ranges [0.0,1.0].

Comment: The value can range from anything. I have another template that has the max range set to 3000 and the value set to 1200, and it worked well. This one has a max value of 5 and current value of 4.17

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got it fixed by changing the computed to the following:

```
    computed: {
    getOverallScore: function () {
        var i;
        var sum = 0;

        // Will get all reviews through API calls
        for (i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + this.items[i].score;
        }

        this.average = Number.parseFloat(sum / this.items.length).toFixed(2);

        return Number.parseFloat(sum / this.items.length);
    },


}
```

Apparently when I use `.toFixed(2)`, the `b-progress` no longer recognises the value as a number but as a string. I tried to convert it using `Number(this.average)` and return that still does not work. I found this very strange though, as the `toFixed` function is part of the built in library and somehow it does not recognise it as a function. The output value is fine so the `toFixed` function works. No idea why it does that.

Comment: toFixed() always returns a string.